# SpellCheck в C#

Tags: c#, winforms

"TextBox не содержит определения для SpellCheck, и не удалось найти метод расширения "SpellCheck", принимающий тип TextBox в качестве первого аргумента".

```
using System.Windows.Controls;
textBox1.SpellCheck.IsEnabled = true;
```

Comment: Посмотрите это https://stackoverflow.com/a/24737073/5796587

Answer (score 0):

Метод `SpellСheck` для `TextBox` из коробки доступен только в `WPF`. Вы используете пример кода, который предназначен исключительно для `WPF` и в `WinForms` он работать не будет.

Для `WinForms` нужно либо искать сторонние элементы управления с поддержкой проверки правописания, либо писать их самостоятельно.